# BAC Calculator keeps ending with exit code 0x0 before it can get to the main function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a BAC calculator on C++ but the program keeps ending with exit code 0x0 before it can get to the main function.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double Calc(double& value_one, double& value_two, double& value_three, double& value_four, double& value_five, double& value_six, double& value_seven, double& value_eight, double& age, double& weight, double& gender);
double OverBAC(double);
double timetillzero(double);
double Timetillbelowlegallimit(double);
string degreeofdrunkness(double);

int main()
{
    // Declaration Statements
    double value_one = 0;
    double value_two = 0;
    double value_three = 0;
    double value_four = 0;
    double value_five = 0;
    double value_six = 0;
    double value_seven = 0;
    double value_eight = 0;
    double value_nine = 0;
    double value_ten = 0;
    double weight = 0;
    double BAC = 0;
    string degreeofdrunkness1;
    double age = 0;
    double number = 0;
    double gender = 0;
    double OverBAC1 = 0;

    // Input
    {
        cout << "There are 12 choices for helping in deciding BAC. 1 = number of number of of 12 oz.regular beer that was drunk. 2 = number of 12 oz.light beer drunk. 3 = number of 4 oz.port house wine drunk. 4 = number of 4 oz.burgundy wine drunk. 5 = the number of 4 oz.rose wine drunk. 6 = number of 1.5 oz. 100 proof vodka drunk. 7 = number of 1.5 oz. 80 proof vodka drunk. 8 = number of 1.5 oz. 80 proof bourbon drunk. 9 = weight. 10 = age. 11 = gender. 12 = execute the program." << endl;

    cin >> number;


    cout << "Please give the number of of 12 oz.regular beer that was drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_one;

    cout << "Please give the number of 12 oz.light beer drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_two;

    cout << "Please give the number of 4 oz.port house wine drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_three;

    cout << "Please give the number of 4 oz.burgundy wine drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_four;

    cout << "Please give the number of 4 oz.rose wine drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_five;

    cout << "Please give the number of 1.5 oz. 100 proof vodka drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_six;

    cout << "Please give the number of 1.5 oz. 80 proof vodka drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_seven;

    cout << "Please give the number of 1.5 oz. 80 proof bourbon drunk." << endl;

    cin >> value_eight;

    cout << "Please enter your weight." << endl;

    cin >> weight;

    cout << "Please input age." << endl;

    cin >> age;

    cout << "Please enter your gender here and press enter. 1=Male 2=Female" << endl;

    cin >> gender;


    //Process
    double Calc(double& value_one, double& value_two, double& value_three, double& value_four, double& value_five, double& value_six, double& value_seven, double& value_eight, double& age, double& weight, double& gender);   // Function Call

    OverBAC(BAC);//Function Call

    degreeofdrunkness1 = degreeofdrunkness(BAC);

        // Function Header

    value_ten = timetillzero(BAC);

    value_nine = Timetillbelowlegallimit(BAC);
    }


    // Output
    cout << "Your BAC is" << BAC << endl;

    cout << "Your OverBAC is" << OverBAC1 << endl;

    cout << "It will take" << value_ten << "hours." << endl;

    cout << "It will take" << value_nine << "hours to get below the legal limit." << endl;

    cout << "You are" << degreeofdrunkness1 << "." << endl; 


    return 0;
}





/**************************************************************************/
// Function Definition : Calc
// Precondition : The number of each type of drink, along with sex, weight, and age are received as call by value parameters.
// Operation : The BAC will be calculated based on the number of each type of drink, age, sex, and weight and return the value.
// Postcondition : The value will be returned as an integer to the calling function.

 //Function Header
double Calc(double value_one, double value_two, double value_three, double value_four, double value_five, double value_six, double value_seven, double value_eight, double age, double weight, double gender)
{
    // Declaration Statements
    double BAC = 0;

    // Process
    if (gender = 1) if (age >= 40) BAC = ((value_one*13.6 + value_two*11.3 + value_three*16.4 + value_four*10.9 + value_five*10.0 + value_six*16.7 + value_seven*16.7 + value_eight*13.7) / ((weight / 2.2046)*0.51) * 100);
    if (gender = 1) if (age > 18) if (age < 40) BAC = ((value_one*13.6 + value_two*11.3 + value_three*16.4 + value_four*10.9 + value_five*10.0 + value_six*16.7 + value_seven*16.7 + value_eight*13.7) / ((weight / 2.2046)*0.61) * 100);
    if (gender = 2) if (age > 18) if (age < 40) BAC = ((value_one*13.6 + value_two*11.3 + value_three*16.4 + value_four*10.9 + value_five*10.0 + value_six*16.7 + value_seven*16.7 + value_eight*13.7) / ((weight / 2.2046)*0.52) * 100);
    if (gender = 2) if (age >= 40) BAC = ((value_one*13.6 + value_two*11.3 + value_three*16.4 + value_four*10.9 + value_five*10.0 + value_six*16.7 + value_seven*16.7 + value_eight*13.7) / ((weight / 2.2046)*0.46) * 100);

    // Output
    return BAC;
}

//**end of calc function***********************************************************//

/****************************************************************************/

// Function Definition : OverBAC
// Precondition : The function receives the BAC integer value from the Calc Module.
// Condition : The function will subtract the legal limit of BAC from the BAC integer that was called and return the answer.
// Postcondition : The value will be returned as an integer to the header module.
    double OverBAC(double BAC)      //Function Header
{
    // Declaration Statements
    double OverBAC1 = 0;

    // Process
    OverBAC1 = (BAC - 0.08);

    // Output
    return OverBAC1;
}
/**end of OverBAC function*********************************************************/


// Function Definition : timetillzero Module :
// Precondition : The function receives the BAC integer value from the Calc Module.
// Operation : The function will divide the BAC by .12 in order to get the hours needed to become completely sober.
// Postcondition : The value will be returned as an integer to the header module.

//**************************************************************************/
    double timetillzero(double BAC)     // Function Header
{
    // Declaration Statements
    double value_ten = 0;

    // Process
    value_ten = BAC / .12;

    //Output
    return value_ten;
}
               /**end of Timetillzero function*************************************************/


        // Timetillbelowlegallimit Module :
        // Precondition : The function receives the BAC integer value from the Calc Module.
        // Operation : The function will divide the BAC value by .12 until it is below .08.
        // Postcondition : The value will be returned as an integer to the header module.
        //**************************************************************//

                double Timetillbelowlegallimit(double BAC)      // Function Header
           {
               // Declaration Statements
               double value_nine = 0;

               // Process
               value_nine = BAC - .08 / .12;

               // Output
               return value_nine;
           }
                          //**end of Timetillbelowlegallimit function***********************************//

//******************************************************************************************************************//
// Message for degree of drunkness module
// Precondition : The function receives the BAC integer value from the main module.
// Operation : If the BAC is a certain value, then the BAC integer will be sent back along with the message.
// Postcondition : The value will be sent back as a string to the header module and send back the degree of drunkness string value
//*******************************************************************************************************************// 
                           string degreeofdrunkness(double BAC)     // Function Header
                          {
                              // Declaration Statement
                              string degreeofdrunkness1;
                              // Process

                              if (BAC > .01) (BAC < .05),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Subclinical";
                              if (BAC > .03) (BAC < .12),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Euphoria";
                              if (BAC > .09) (BAC < .25),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Excitement";
                              if (BAC > .18) (BAC < .30),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Confusion";
                              if (BAC > .25) (BAC < .40),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Stupor";
                              if (BAC > .35) (BAC < .50),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Coma";
                              if (BAC > .45) degreeofdrunkness1 = "Death";

                              // Output

                              return degreeofdrunkness1;
                          }

                          //**end of function********************************************************//
```

Comment: What do you mean "program keeps ending before it can get to the main function"? What output do you see?

Comment: That's just it, as soon as it gets to the function calls, it just exits with code 0x0 and that's the output. It just skips everything else and ceases to function.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like an excellent case to use with a debugger.

Comment: It actually got through the debugger well enough.

Answer (score 1):

One apparent error is inside your `main`:

```
    double Calc(double& value_one, double& value_two, 
                double& value_three, double& value_four, 
                 double& value_five, double& value_six, 
                 double& value_seven, double& value_eight, 
           double& age, double& weight, double& gender);   // Function Call
```

You are doing a function declaration, if you are doing function call, do the following:

```
double res = double Calc(value_one,value_two, value_three, 
         value_four, value_five, value_six,  
          value_seven, value_eight, age, weight, gender);
```

You need to consume the returned result later in your `main`.

Besides, it makes no sense to declare `age` and `gender` as `double`.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled and ran your code. It runs as expected.

g++ 4.9.2 no flags.

You have plenty of syntax that is nonsensical though, e.g.

```
if (BAC > .01) (BAC < .05),  degreeofdrunkness1 = "Subclinical";
```

Comment: Yep, but I tried to run it in microsoft visual studio in C++ and it apparently ended before the first function call. I tried to redefine the code as float too and it still ended before the function calls were even noticed.

Comment: The functions gets called and it works as written.  You are just unfamiliar with your tools and c++.